# update-grub => Invalid output format export. Choose from value, device, list, or full

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, grub, uefi

Ciao!

How are you?

Before UEFI, my looped ISO-s were working, I could use via ISO files in the HDD with Clonezilla and SystemRescueCD on a ext4 partition, but now I get this error:

```
patrikx3@workstation:~/Projects/sygnus/ng-ivr/ng-ivr-project$ sudo -i
[sudo] password for patrikx3: 
root@workstation:~# update-grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found background image: grub.png
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-35-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-35-generic
Invalid output format export. Choose from value,
    device, list, or full
Invalid output format export. Choose from value,
    device, list, or full
Invalid output format export. Choose from value,
    device, list, or full
Invalid output format export. Choose from value,
    device, list, or full
Invalid output format export. Choose from value,
    device, list, or full
Invalid output format export. Choose from value,
    device, list, or full
Invalid output format export. Choose from value,
    device, list, or full
Invalid output format export. Choose from value,
    device, list, or full
Invalid output format export. Choose from value,
    device, list, or full
Invalid output format export. Choose from value,
    device, list, or full
Invalid output format export. Choose from value,
    device, list, or full
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda2@/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
done
root@workstation:~# cd /media/live/
root@workstation:/media/live# ll
total 993712
-rw-rw-r-- 1 patrikx3 patrikx3 220200960 Sep 30 18:08 clonezilla-live-2.5.2-31-amd64.iso
-rw-rw-r-- 1 patrikx3 patrikx3 279969792 Sep 30 18:09 gparted-live-0.29.0-1-amd64.iso
drwx------ 2 root     root         16384 Sep 30 19:20 lost+found
-rw-rw-r-- 1 patrikx3 patrikx3 517359616 Sep 30 18:09 systemrescuecd-x86-5.1.1.iso
root@workstation:/media/live#
```

Do you guys why it is not working anymore magic allocation or something like this when I boot with Clonzilla and `update-grub` is giving this error as it says above.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an older *util-linux* version than `update-grub` expects.

The `blkid -o export` option was added in *util-linux* v2.18.

Comment: i have ```util-linux/now 2.27.1-6ubuntu3.3 amd64 [installed,local]```

Comment: but i can see ```blkid -o export``` is saying invlid output format export.

Comment: so i just have to wait until it works or is it the kernel too new? and revert to 4.8 instead of 4.10 kernel?

Comment: looks like an ubuntu issue with the versions?

Comment: i don't get it, i got 2.27 for ```libblkid1``` as well, why it saying the ```export``` format is not understood?